# add swing component into javafx tab

Tags: java, swing, javafx, jframe

I have a JavaFX and a separate swing project. Now i need to add that jframe into my JavaFX project inside a Tab. By doing some research i go to know that i can not add jframe directly so i need SwingNode. I am able to add jframe without any error but the frame gui get very disturb. jfram is not visible at first time and when i hover my mouse on over it, it become visible only for that area, except that the hint popup also not visible. 
Below is the code. Please help me with adding swing component inside javafx successfully.

```
  SyntaxTester ob = new SyntaxTester();
        SwingNode swingnode = new SwingNode();
        swingnode.setContent(ob.getEditor()); //getEditor returns jEditorPane
        tab.setContent(swingnode);
```

Answer (score 3):

`JFrame` comes with its own decorations and they might be causing the issues. Instead of adding JFrame - add `JFrame#getContentPane()`.

Comment: Wrap the swingnode in BorderPane or ScrollPane. That seems to make it work.

Comment: Yes thank you, it work for appearance issue, now gui loaded clear but hint popup still not appearing

Comment: any idea why hint popup not working. it is the last issue i stuck.

Comment: Try adding a mouse listener to swingnode and pass them through to swing component through `java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent`. I don't know whether it is worth the trouble though :)